# RStudio scripts don't show any output

Tags: r, rstudio

I just joined the community, hope I can ask my question precise enough.

So the problem is the following: For some unknown reason any code I type into a script does almost always not generate any output. But there is no error. Functions, in general, seem to work if I type them directly in the console. Most peculiar about this: Sometimes it does work.

[image]

Comment: My guess is that you click "run" when you are not on a line with code in it (so then you execute an empty line).

Comment: That was a bit stupid of me. But thank you so much for this tiny but very substantial clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the lines that you want to run! Before clicking the run button, make sure you have selected the lines of code. Maybe it's the problem ;)